# Location fetching

Tags: java, android, location

i just used the above code to fetch the location.It just works fine in my test phone nokkia 2 and also in redmi 5a. But it is not working in some other phones
like moto g5, Samsung j6 etc

i just check the permissions and its all good.permission for location is on,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

these user permissions are given....
Still in some phones,this code is not working..
please help me to find a solution.

```
 private void location() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Turn On Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            return;
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (!enabled) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "please turn on your location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

        if (provider != null && !provider.equals("")) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }

            Location location1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Location location2 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            Location location3 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
            final int minTime = 1000;



            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, 0, this);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, minTime, 0, this);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, minTime, 0, this);


            if (location1 != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location1);
            } else if (location2 != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location2);
            } else if (location3 != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location3);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "network error..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("TAG", "your location can't get...." + location1);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Provider Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code instead of `LocationManager`

```
FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient =  LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }
                });
```